# ZeroMQ, how to make two socket speaking to one without mixing messages

Tags: perl, sockets, zeromq

This is my situation: I have a server that opens a socket (ZMQ_DEALER) and bind it with ipc to /tmp/server.ipc. Then I have a shell that is connected to the server with another socket (ZMQ_DEALER). The shell sends to the server some commands and the server executes them.
But, sometimes, some commands are scripts that needs to send other commands to the server.

The problem is that I'm not able to select the socket that has to receive the answer from the server. So it happens that the messages for the shell are processed by the script and vice versa.

Can you help me to understand how to solve this problem? Am I using the wrong socket type?

I have to solve this using only one socket and not two.

If it can help, I'm using the perl bindings of ZeroMQ.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please clarify: "...with another socket(ZMQ_DEALER)",  but you already defined (ZMQ_DEALER).  I was thinking this: shell>>socket>>server, but you said: " But, sometimes, some commands are scripts that needs to send other commands to the server." I thought the scripts were already on the server?

Comment: ZMQ_DEALER is the socket type. I added it just be sure that I was not using the wrong socket type. The server has the role of starting some services (DNS, HTTPD and PROXY) and do start some "test" against these services. So, if you ask the server to start a test, the test itself has then to start some services with certain specific configuration. That's why the test itself needs to speak with the server. The messages are mixed between the shell (that launched the test) and the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution thanks to michelp on ZeroMQ irc channel.

You can find the solution here:

http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Router-to-Dealer-Routing